# Учесть кавычки в JSON C#

Tags: c#, json

Получаю с сервера строку вида:

```
[1510,[0,0,0,0,0,0,0],0,[{\"195562162_456239289\":[\"HammAli &amp; Navai Им грош цена\",\"https:\\/\\/m.vk.com\\/mp3\\/audio_api_unavailable.mp3...\",\"HammAli &amp; Navai\",\"Им грош цена\",\"\",false],\"195562162_456239288\":[\"Градусы &amp; Кравц Выходи за меня\",\"https:\\/\\/m.vk.com\\/mp3\\/audio_api_unavailable.mp3...\",\"Градусы &amp; Кравц\",\"Выходи за меня\",\"\",false]},[\"\"],\"\"]]
```

Если получаю такую строку, то тут все хорошо работает. Я регуляркой достаю, что находится между { и } т.к. если парсить сразу эту строку, выдается исключение, что нельзя спарсить массив, нужен объект
Но получается казус, если в какой либо строке присутствует кавычка (Например в строчке будет одна кавычка `\"Им грош \" цена\"`). Тогда выдается исключение `Invalid property identifier character...` Как это решить?

Comment: А почему вы пользуетесь регулярками, вы не знаете о существовании парсеров JSON?

Comment: Использую `JObject.Parse();` но говорю же, если попытаться сразу спарсить полученную строку, это не получается (Exeption: "Error reading JObject from JsonReader. Current JsonReader item is not an object: StartArray. Path '', line 1, position 1."). Поэтому выделаю конкретно то, что мне надо.

Comment: У меня всего пару вопросов, что вы вообще хотите добиться в своем приложение, ибо как я понимаю - прочесть музыку из "Вконтакте", но ведь они уже давно закрыли API и в вашем `JSON` это прекрасно видно. Исходя из этого другой вопрос, где вы получили этот ужаснейший `JSON`?

Comment: Я знаю как расшифровать ссылку, так что не волнуйтесь. Получил через POST запрос на https://m.vk.com/audios+id с параметрами _ajax = 1 и offset = 0

Comment: Ну так используйте `JArray`, раз уж это массив.

Comment: Расшифровать ссылку, когда каждый трек называется `audio_api_unavailable.mp3`? )

Comment: Я обрезал длиннющий параметр у этой ссылки, чтобы у вас глаза не болели читать. Буду знать про JArray теперь, спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте JArray вместо JObject так как у вас массив а не объект

```
var str = "[1510,[0,0,0,0,0,0,0],0,[{\"195562162_456239289\":[\"HammAli &amp; Navai Им грош цена\",\"https:\\/\\/m.vk.com\\/mp3\\/audio_api_unavailable.mp3...\",\"HammAli &amp; Navai\",\"Им грош цена\",\"\",false],\"195562162_456239288\":[\"Градусы &amp; Кравц Выходи за меня\",\"https:\\/\\/m.vk.com\\/mp3\\/audio_api_unavailable.mp3...\",\"Градусы &amp; Кравц\",\"Выходи за меня\",\"\",false]},[\"\"],\"\"]]";

var array = JArray.Parse(str);
```